# Magento 2.4: Execution of commands consumes whole memory and hangs system

Tags: magento

I copied magento source code from server on local machine. After firing "bin/magento cache:clean" command causes whole 16 GB memory consumption and exit with an error "PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 15032385536 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0"

Ubuntu 18.04, PHP7.4 and Magento 2.4. Not sure how to fix this issue, i tried everything but couldn't fix this issue. I really appreciate your time and help in advance.

Comment: I was using ubantu desktop version and magento 2.4 on this duo i faced this issue. I moved to ubantu server then somehow issue not reproduced there. Not sure what exactly was the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remote machine may have an app/etc/env.php with customised caches for Redis and other services.

Try installing a demo store on your local machine with demo products and then compare the app/etc/env.php file to see the cache differences.

Comment: I copied same file and there is no other services presently I am using, but definitely I will take a close look to verify it. Thanks for reply